# How to display current date on page load in bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

Please find my program below,

How to show Today's date in the div.. as per below example .. by default it show Todays date but its showing previous month to today's date... if I click on Today from drop down still it shows date from previous month to today's date. On page load itself how to show from and to date as Today's date

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />        

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        //alert($('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY')));
    }
    cb(moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment());

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

});
</script>        

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="reportrange" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20%">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
            <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is January month 0 or month 1?

Comment: what do you mean by 0 based or 1 based...can you please clairfy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected, you need to set current date and time in you local machine.

Add this change `cb(moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment());`

Comment: my system current date and time set properly. I've attached screenshot in my post.. its showing from past month 26th to today 25th

Comment: Got it.. but to show from and to date as current day - I've update cb(moment(), moment()); - Its working as I expected. Thank you :)